# Is there a way to change the delay of the Tooltip on Browsers?

Tags: internet, google-chrome, browser, tooltip

I don't like the long delay for Tooltip.I was wondering if there was a way to change the delay of the tooltip in Chrome brower.

Comment: What "tooltip" exactly are you referring to? And are you sure it's an Ubuntu issue or an issue with Chrome for Linux or an issue with Chrome in general? If the issue hasn't anything to do with Ubuntu, you may get more "eyeballs" over at superuser.com.